# Dividing the earth into regions

Tags: google-maps, gis

I want to divide the earth into separate regions I can assign objects to.

Basically, I have a map (from Google Maps or somewhere else, the exact source is not important). On this map I want to define regions of different type, e.g. you might have regions of type A, B or C - or even regions without a type.

My question is: How could you implement this? Which techniques to use?

Basically, several options come to my mind:

- Project the map to a 2D rectangle using a map projection (sub question: Which one to use?), and define the regions as rectangles. The clear advantage is that besides the projection I do not have to care about complex mathematical formulas. The drawback is that I need to project every input to the projected map.
- Use a sphere, and calculate the area of the region using trigonometric functions. This is definitely more work regarding the formulas, nevertheless you do not need a projection.

What other possibilities are there?
What are the individual advantages and disadvantages?

The reason why I want to do this is because the end user may use his or her mobile device to get his / her current location. Then the app should be able to get what kind of region the user is in.

Any ideas?

Comment: Maybe what you are searching: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/maptypes#TileCoordinates

Answer (score 0):

Most likely maps application uses a spatial index to subdivide a map. A spatial index is a space filling curve. There is also a more complex curve like the hilbert curve. Microsoft bing maps uses a z curve. It's also possible to use a 3d spatial index but it's very complicated. But most likely it's just for tiling and faster query the map.

1. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb259689.aspx

Answer (score -2):

I have good news for you: the maps you are looking (google maps et al) are already 2d projected so you don't have to worry about projections.

Good luck

Comment: Obviously the person that downvoted me has no idea of what maps are, Have you ever heard of mercator projections?

Comment: I think everbody knows about projection. The question was about tiling. It's also possible to subdivide a sphere.

Comment: right, the question is about tiling but the op is missing the point by thinking about projections since the maps he will be using are already projections. if I remember right, Google and the others don't provide the raw data which means you can't do projections on your own